# What is the "scan" token/keyword/feature in Java?

Tags: java, keyword

I was recently debugging some code which led me through an exercise of stepping through the source for the String class. While looking through the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#2409), I came across:

```
/* Now check if there are any characters that need to be changed. */
    scan: {
        for (firstUpper = 0 ; firstUpper < len; ) {
            char c = value[firstUpper];
            if ((c >= Character.MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE)
                    && (c <= Character.MAX_HIGH_SURROGATE)) {
                int supplChar = codePointAt(firstUpper);
                if (supplChar != Character.toLowerCase(supplChar)) {
                    break scan;
                }
                firstUpper += Character.charCount(supplChar);
            } else {
                if (c != Character.toLowerCase(c)) {
                    break scan;
                }
                firstUpper++;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
```

I don't think I've ever seen the `scan` keyword. I did an internet search and even read the [Java keyword spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9), but it doesn't mention `scan` as an official keyword. Can anyone point me to some documentation on this keyword/token/feature?

Comment: It's the name of the loop. It's used later to call break to that specific loop in the third if.

Comment: It's a label. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: And specifically it is neither a keyword nor a feature. It is a user-defined label value.